# Random ordering of a set in Java?

Tags: java, set

I ran this code several times (Java 11):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    Set<String> elements = Set.of("Neptunium", "Iodine", "Thallium", "Carbon", "Calcium");
    System.out.println(elements);
    elements = elements.stream()
            .map(n -> n.substring(0, 1))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    for (String s : elements) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

and the results are:

```
[Thallium, Carbon, Neptunium, Iodine, Calcium]
CTIN
-----------------------
[Thallium, Calcium, Iodine, Neptunium, Carbon]
CTIN
-----------------------
[Neptunium, Iodine, Calcium, Thallium, Carbon]
CTIN
...
```

The ordering of the first set `Set.of("Neptunium", "Iodine", "Thallium", "Carbon", "Calcium");` is nondeterministic, as I expect it to be. However the second one `Collectors.toSet()` is always the same. What kind of magic is this?

Comment: "Non-deterministic" here doesn't mean "always different'. It just means "don't rely on the fact that it is or isn't ordered". In other words, it's an implementation detail.

Comment: Well, as Federico stated a set can or can not be ordered which "non-deterministic" means. You just don't know. `Collectors.toSet()` creates `HashSet` and if that implementation uses the same order to iterate (likely based on buckets and collision lists in the internal map) then that's ok. It doesn't _have_ to be different there's just no guarantee that it will be the same.

Comment: Also, there are `Set`s that are ordered ([`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) comes to mind). So the assumption that a `Set` is *always* not ordered is wrong.

Comment: If you have a look at the sets created by `Set.of(...)` you see that they internally actually seem to have a deterministic structure (depends on elements and their order) but the iterator uses a random number to introduce randomness (at least it will select a random starting index).

Comment: Java set ordering is not "nondeterministic". I'm not sure where you got this from, The javadoc states "The iteration order of set elements is unspecified and is subject to change." - it is **unspecified**. So any order, including a constant one that never changes, is consistent with the guarantees of the `java.util.Set` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Set.of()` doesn't have a defined iteration order and it is subjected to change.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable)

> The iteration order of set elements is unspecified and is subject to change.

[`Collectors.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()) doesn't define which `Set` implementation is used.

> `public static <T> Collector<T,?,Set<T>> toSet()`
>
> Returns a Collector that accumulates the input elements into a new `Set`. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Set returned; if more control over the returned `Set` is required, use `toCollection(Supplier)`.

Currently the supplier is hardcoded to `HashSet::new`. But it can change in the future. So if you need something predictable, better to pass a concrete `Set` implementation as supplier. Because it is returning `HashSet` currently and you are passing elements in same order while creating, iteration is returning the data in a particular order every time based on bucket locations. That's why the result is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List` to be sure of the order of elements, or if you need `Set`, use `LinkedHashSet`.

```java
Set<String> elements = new LinkedHashSet<>(
        List.of("Neptunium", "Iodine", "Thallium", "Carbon", "Calcium"));
```